# How to check in using access token in Foursquare

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, foursquare, checkin

I would like to integrate the "Foursquare check in" feature into my iOS application. I am able to fetch the Foursquare access token using `UIWebView`. But i am struggling to implement check in feature. I did searched lot in Google to implement check in feature using access token. I found the following tutorial [Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) but this one didn't helped me to integrate in `xcode`

Please help me, in case you know how to implement check in feature in Foursqure. It would be really helpful

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have an access token, the hard part is done! You can use the access token in either a call in a [client library](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2) or you can make a direct HTTP POST request to our [checkins/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) endpoint. The URI should look like, before adding any other optional parameters:

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&venueId=VENUE_ID&v=20130822`

Note that Foursquare also released [native auth for iOS](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-ios-oauth), which can make getting the access token even easier without having to use a UIWebView.

Comment: Is there any API to get venue id for the input of lat and long

Comment: Yes, you can use our [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) or [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoints

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

[Git Hub Demo Code](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2)

Comment: Can i check in without providing venue id

Comment: No you cannot check-in without a venueId because you need to check-in to a specific venue!

Comment: Is there any API to get venue id for the input of lat and long

Comment: @thavasidurai, Can you please tell me, How will you perform check in??

Comment: You can download the sample project from above link in this project check in feature has been integrated

Comment: so, as per demo what's your problem??